# VueJS dom doesn't refresh when array changed

Tags: javascript, laravel, dom, vuejs2

I have a custom directive called "sortable" but I ran into a problem with the DOM. The problem is when I dragged and dropped an item the array is changed but the DOM isn't.

**This is my custom directive:**

```
 Vue.directive('sortable', {
    bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        // Initialize sortable
        this.sortable = Sortable.create(el, {});
        console.debug("Sortable initialized");

        this.sortable.option("onUpdate", function(event) {
            binding.value.move(event.oldIndex, event.newIndex);
            var updated = binding.value;
            Vue.set(tasks, updated);
        });
    }
});
```

**And this is how I create my Vue instance:**

```
app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        subtotal: 0,
        tasks: [
            {name: '', quantity: '', rate: 80, costs: ''}
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        newTask: function() {
            this.tasks.push({name: '', quantity: '', rate: 80, costs: ''})
        },
        deleteTask: function(index) {
            this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
            this.calculateTotal();
        },
        calculateCosts: function(event, value, index) {
            this.tasks[index].costs = event.target.value * value;
            this.calculateTotal();
        },
        calculateTotal: function() {
            this.subtotal = 0;
            _.forEach(this.tasks, $.proxy(function(task) {
                this.subtotal += task.costs;
            }, this));
        }
    }
});
```

In my template I use: `v-for="(task, index) in tasks"`. Did I something wrong?

Comment: when You drag and drop an item, which method is getting called?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods), the following methods will trigger view updates. The wrapped methods are:

- push()
- pop()
- shift()
- unshift()
- splice()
- sort()
- reverse()

However I see you are also doing this assignment in `calculateCosts`  method, which will not trigger the mutation, due to [caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) in vue:

```
this.tasks[index].costs = event.target.value * value;
```

This can be replaced with the following to trigger the mutation and update the view with the help of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

```
var newVal = Object.assign({}, this.tasks[index], {costs: event.target.value * value})
Vue.set(this.tasks, index, newVal)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I placed this exact same question on the Laravel forum and it is fixed now. The only problem was that I forget the :key=tasks inside of the DOM. But thanks anyways.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it was bugging me for a while. But I got it fixed because of your comment. So thank you!

For future readers, it's actually :key=task instead of :key=tasks.

Answer (score 1):

To make vue recept it, use a proper unique key from the array value, not the array index:

```
<!-- use value.id in :key, not index -->
<div v-for="(value, index) in values" :key="value.id"> .... </div>
```