# Vue.js v-for generated html block capturing collapse state with two way data binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to capture click action state (for collaps function) within html v-for generated block. To achieve this, I'm using declared data table, and it looks like state is being captured correctly. Below I'm ataching simplified v-for section, where I display state after click action. Displayed state is always false, even though after click, console.log shows table fields changes. Can someone please try to explain me why is that, and how to achieve what is expected here? I'm pretty new to vue, and must be doing something wrong...

```
<div v-for="address in userAddressData">
  <a @click="expandControl(address.id)">
  Address {{expandArea[address.id]}}
  </a>
</div>
...
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      userAddressData: '',
      expandArea: [false,false,false]
    }
  },
methods: {
  expandControl (id) {
    this.expandArea[id] = !this.expandArea[id]
    console.log(this.expandArea)
  }
},
...
```

Comment: I'm not following, what's the issue?

Comment: why are you using `v-for` for a data type that is not a collection (array) or is it an array cause i see empty string in the instantiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, the problem you are having is that the template is not being updated according to the `data`, as we can see on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gen1kL3y/

This is issue is related to how [Vue Reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) works.

You can find another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267487/vuejs-dom-doesnt-refresh-when-array-changed) and I made a working JS fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/vz11zdjc/

Basically, instead of setting the value as `this.expandArea[id] = !this.expandArea[id]`, you should (among other options) use `Vue.set(this.expandArea, id, !this.expandArea[id])`

Comment: Wow, this is great! Works! Thank you for quick turnaround on this issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind checking it as the right answer, then? Thanks.